# Server not accessible from the internet despite everything

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port, port-forwarding

I don't have a static ip, so it changes sometimes, meaning I have to change things like port forwarding rules for my web server and SSH, etc. However this time, despite *everything*, it's not accessible from the internet. (I've changed my website's DNS records, changed all the port forwarding rules. Nothing else needed to be changed).

Here's the port forward rules - they just don't appear to be working.

[image]

I even put the server in my router's DMZ - still nothing.

All my programs seem to be working, I can access everything locally, just not on the internet. I double-checked my UFW rules, and they're all fine.

I have no additional firewalls.

My webserver uses Cloudflare's reverse proxy, but it's neither accessible through that, or when I directly connect to the server.

Do you think it's a problem with my ISP? This has only been happening for the last couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed

I contacted my ISP - they had closed ***all my ports*** by mistake.

I don't know how, but they managed to.

I was going nuts trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.